# Can we provide NFT royalties to 2 addresses through Opensea?

Tags: nft, erc-721, royalties

I have an NFT collection and want to split the royalty between 2 addresses. After some research, I stumbled upon the `contractURI()` method where we can add the information like:

```
function contractURI() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "URI";
    }
```

JSON File:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "image": "IMAGELINK.png",
  "external_link": "https://www.google.com/",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 250, 
  "fee_recipient": "ADDRESS OF A USER" 
}
```

Is there any way to add 2 addresses and 2 different fees as royalty which can be split between the addresses? Or any other way which can do this task?